# Use SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, localdb

I need to create a Database in Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB for compatibility issues with previous versions of Visual Studio.
From what I found, if I need to connect a table from previous versions of Visual Studio, I just need to change the `Data Source` from `(localdb)\v11.0` to `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

Now I want to know if I can make the opposite, changing the `Data Source` from the Database that I created in Visual Studio 2015 to `(localdb)\v11.0`, will it work without problems and without lost of data if I use it in previous versions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with a friend how only has Visual Studio 2013 installed and it appear that it doesn't work..